# How to pass same props to multiple components correctly?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that based on its props, renders another component with almost same props, something like this:

```
render() {
  return(
    <Component>
      {this.renderComponent()}
    </Component>
  )


renderComponent() {
  switch (condition) {
    case "A": {
      return (
        <ComponentA
         many={...}
         same={...}
         things={...}
         oneDifferentProp="A"
        />
    }
    case "B": {
      return (
        <WrapperComponent>
          <ComponentB
           many={...}
           same={...}
           things={...}
           oneDifferentProp="B"
          />
          <SomethingOther>
        </WrapperComponent>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

So how do I make this nice and scalable and easily readable?

Answer (score 9):

You could make use of the [spread syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) here.

```
renderComponent() {
  // Create/pass in this object however you want
  let sharedProps = { many: 1, same: 2, things: 3 }; 

  switch (condition) {
    case "A":
      return (
        <ComponentA
         oneDifferentProp="A"
         {...sharedProps}
        />
      )
    case "B":
      return (
        <WrapperComponent>
          <ComponentB
           oneDifferentProp="B"
           {...sharedProps}
          />
          <SomethingOther />
        </WrapperComponent>
      )
  }
}
```